# Can we open a third party application in salesforce app inside an iframe?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, iframe

I have a situation where I need to integrate a third party application which is not a salesforce application.
If I do it, does this violates the security tests of Salesforce Application done by Salesforce team, as the application is a full-fledged web application having everything from presentation logic, business logic and Database logic and has its own database.

Is this can be done if we consider salesforce's security testing method.

Please share your experiences?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what Salesforce Canvas was made for.  Take a look:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm